what is Isuue to switchIfEmpty() method order in ExceptionTranslationWebFilter?
My spring security version is 6.2.3.
My security filter sequence is

{ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter@12858}
{HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter@12859}
{ReactorContextWebFilter@12860}
{JwtAuthenticationFilter@12861}
{SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter@12862}
{ServerRequestCacheWebFilter@12863}
{ExceptionTranslationWebFilter@9703}
{JwtAuthorizationFilter@9787}
{AuthorizationWebFilter@12864}

If JwtAuthorizationFilter throws AccessDeniedException after authentication, the sequence of operation in ExceptionTranslationWebFilter.java filter is

exchange.getPrincipal()
switchIfEmpty()
filter()
flatMap()
It happens in sequence, and ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint and ServerAccessDeniedHandler occur in sequence.

Finally, the ServerAccessDeniedHandler operates and the results are as expected, but it is strange to throw ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint in an authorization error.
Analyzing and debugging ExceptionTranslationWebFilter.java
The exception that occurred after it was authenticated as a result of what I thought is that ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint does not occur.

you have to use stackoverflow Tools to organize your questions, like the code container , etc...
